# Appropriate Statistical test for Analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics, ab-test

I have built and tested a computer application, which involved two participant groups (Group-A with existing knowledge of databases and Group-B without knowledge of databases).

I was required to apply test of statistical tests to determine if the rating and perception of built application was same among both groups. I used the system log file and questionnaire tools for collecting information used for histograms, means, skewness and kurtosis values.

The question I am looking to ask, Is the use of statistical tests (histograms, means, skewness and kurtosis) values used for measuring the differences of data / rating / perception between both groups were appropriate?