# Appropriate statistical analysis to use

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, statistical-learning

I have built and tested a computer application, which involved two participant groups (Group-A with existing knowledge of databases and Group-B without knowledge of databases). I was required to apply statistical tests to determine if the perception and rating given to the application was same among both groups (based on the data recorded in the form of questionnaires). The participants from both groups filled out questionnaires (with 10 questions to rate based on Likert scales) to rate the system based on their experience during testing it.

Is the use of statistical tests (histograms, means, skewness and kurtosis), used for measuring the differences of data / rating / perception between both groups appropriate? What I am trying to see is that if / how much participants' ratings in group A differ from the ratings given by the participants in group-B, for each question of the questionnaire.

Comment: Can you say a little more about the nature of your data? Are the questionnaires likert-type ordinal ratings? How many items are there? Are you combining the items into a single score? How? How many levels do the items have? What is the nature of the log files? Are these counts of the number of actions a user took to achieve some goal? Are you using the types of actions or only the total number? Do users perform more than one task? Are the tasks essentially the same or different? Etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'difference in normality' there. If you're testing to see whether two groups have the same distribution, there are tests for that (for example, a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test). If you want to test the groups individually for normality, there are tests for that, too. Please clarify what you're actually trying to find out.

Comment: This duplicates an existing question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129067/appropriate-statistical-test-for-analysis). Please [merge your accounts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and delete one of the two questions (I suggest this one since the other has answers already).

Comment: The participants from both group filled questionnaires (with 10 questions to rate based on Likert scale) on rating the system based on their experience during testing it. 

What I am trying to see is that if/how much participant(group-A)'s rating differ to the rating given by the participants from group-B, for each question of questionnaire.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your measures (histograms, means, skew, and kurtosis) are a good first step.  Those statistics are called descriptive in that they describe your outcome information.  Now you want to use an inferential statistics to determine whether or not the difference between your two groups are significantly different and not just due to chance.  The easiest test would be a t-test.  Simply, a t-test determines whether or not the mean scores of your two groups are different.  If you use Excel, you can find a t-test on that program (as well as many other statistical tests assessing the differences between groups).  Hope this helps.

Comment: My guess is that the idea the two groups would be the same is nonsensical in this context. It will probably be better to focus on meaningful ways to quantify the differences (ie appropriate measures of effect size). But the best way is hard to know w/o knowing more about the situation & the data.